# Unity firebase notifications custom image

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, icons, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have decided to implement Firebase notifications into my unity project. The issue is that for notifications I want to use custom image, but that image is also used as app image (app_icon). I tried to modify manifest where I put into MessagingUnityPlayerActivity activity custom notification image (notificon) for displaying notification icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="${applicationId}"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
         UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
         notification data payloads in the background. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:icon="@drawable/notificon"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService"
             android:exported="false"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to modify it and delete some tags, but then the build wond compile. I should also mention that I have multiple manifests in my project and tried them to merge together but unsuccessfully. But this shouldnt be the problem since this is the only manifest with android:icon propery.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

1. Make an image (a white on transparent version of game icon, png) under folder "Assets\Plugins\Android\res\drawable.
2. In my case, the name of my image is "small_icon.png" then in "Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml", add it after  opening tag:

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/small_icon" />`

Your AndroidManifest.xml should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="${applicationId}" 
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/small_icon" />
<activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
</activity>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting a `res` folder inside `Assets/Plugins/Android` using AAB is **obsolete** and will prevent you from building.

Since I was too lazy to install Android Studio to build a custom AAR I solved it by placing a ZIP-Archive into the `Assets/Plugins/Android` folder, with the `res` folder inside (res folder created with [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=card_giftcard&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_card_giftcard) as mentioned in an other answer) and the following snippet inside a `AndroidManifest.xml` next to the `res` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
package="com.google.firebase.messaging" 
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="1.0">
<application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/YOURICONIMAGENAMEWITHOUTEXTENSION" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Then change the ZIP file extension to AAR in the explorer.
You can then specify the icons name from the senders side.
More details of the AAR anatomy [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library).

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the manifest. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qvauO9X21E8) worked for me:

> So you should be able to add your
>   icon(s) to
>   Assets/Plugins/Android/res/drawable/
>   and reference it name

Then, in the notification json, specify your icon. For example:

```
"notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "text" : "Text",
        "icon" : "MyIcon"
    }
```

Note: I used one of [these icons](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=card_giftcard&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_card_giftcard).

Answer (score 0):

> Then change the ZIP file extension to AAR in the explorer. You can
> then specify the icons name from the senders side. More details of the
> AAR anatomy [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library).

If you just change the extension to aar, it won't compile.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unityLibrary:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform firebase_notification_icon-.aar (:firebase_notification_icon:) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\...\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ea6ac2b3d0993f0958d52cbbdfbd76ea\jetified-firebase_notification_icon.aar.
         > entry
```

AAR-file must be created in Android Studio. Since it must contain a number of required files such as AndroidManifest.xml, classes.jar, etc.