# Unable To Change Firebase Push Notification Icon in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to Change the default Firebase Icon that is displayed when sending Push Notification (Firebase Cloud Messaging), but I'm not able to do so in Unity, I tried Many methods available on Google and StackOverFlow, But None of Them Worked. Please Help me with Your Solutions...

I tried adding `res` folder to `Assets\Plugins\Android` but it shows `OBSOLETE - Providing Android resources in Assets/Plugins/Android/res was removed`, I also tried using `.aar` method but it shows

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unityLibrary:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform ic_stat_sb-.aar (:ic_stat_sb:) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
```

Comment: Did you try this? [Unity firebase notifications custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052913/unity-firebase-notifications-custom-image) The problem with saying you tried many methods without specifying any of them is that we have to guess what you didn't try and hope that whatever you did try was done correctly. Try to be more specific about what you've tried and how you tried it.

Comment: I tried Anh Ngoc's Solution but got ```OBSOLETE - Providing Android resources in Assets/Plugins/Android/res was removed``` and while using Codehai's solution it shows ```@drawble/ic_stat_sb not found```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is to build an AAR library that contains your icons. Here's how you can do it with Android Studio.

- After installing Android Studio, start a fresh empty project, or use an existing one, the project doesn't matter.
- Click on File => New => New Module...
- Change the name to what you want (ex: NotificationIcon)
- I've selected Java and min sdk of 26 to match my unity settings, if you have higher/lower sdk version setup in unity I would suggest using the same one.
  [image: New Module]
- Click Next and you will see your library in the explorer window of android Studio, if it doesn't show up right away, wait a minute it might be creating it.
- Inside the library files you will find manifests folder, open it and change the AndroidManifest.xml to this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <application>
           <meta-data
            
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_card_giftcard" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

- Make sure to change the name of the icon `ic_stat_card_giftcard` to what your icon name is.
- At this point you will get an error that the res folder doesn't exist and Android studio will suggest to generate it with an xml file inside.
- Generate the res folder, delete the xml file and paste your icons inside the res folder, you should have a file structure like this, given that your icons were each in its own folder per resolution.
  PS: if you are unable to paste directly in Android Studio, right click the res folder, open In => Explorer and you can paste normally there.

[image]

- Last step is to build this library now, click on Gradle, its either on left or right panels, first button top left (Execute Gradle Task) and type in build click Enter.

[image]

- Gradle should start the build and once done you can find your .aar file in the same directory as your application under MyApplication<YourLibraryName>\build\outputs\aar
- Take that aar file and copy it into Unity assets/Plugins/Android and build your game.

**You should be able to see the icon once you receive a notification from firebase!**